# How to call a jquery plugin method from another plugin

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to call a plugin's method from other plugin ?.So it makes the inner plugin to work from the outer plugin , I need to call one method of the inner plugin from the outer plugin , My inner plugin is ,

```
(function ( $ ) {
onscrollHelper: function (scrolltop,virtualization) {
            var div = $(".gridcontent");
            div.scrollTop(scrolltop);
            _onScroll();
        },
_onScroll:function(){
//some def
}
}( jQuery ));
```

Now how to call that onscrollHelper method from my implementation with arguments , such that it invokes other methods in that plugin via _onscroll() method defined .

Comment: `$.onscrollHelper( arg1, arg2)`

Comment: @palash I want to call onscrollHelper from other plugin , not within this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Create a name for your plugin like this,

```
(function ( $ ) {
MyPlugin={
onscrollHelper: function (scrolltop,virtualization) {
            var div = $(".gridcontent");
            div.scrollTop(scrolltop);
            _onScroll();
        },
_onScroll:function(){
//some def
}
}
}( jQuery ));
```

Then you can access it using

```
MyPlugin.onscrollHelper();
```

Check this [fuddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/Lsf98/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'd tried this , but it appears as "MyPlugin"(plugin name) is undefined .

Comment: Hi subash , thanks for your approach , It worked for me in a different way.